# Cant run selenium with User profile

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium was working until i tried to add a chrome profile and now i keep getting an error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# chrome driver path to file downloade
service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 3') 
browser=webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

browser.get('https://google.com')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CA27892+54818]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C996AC2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C84DA3B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C87C202]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C87802E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C8B67FB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C8AE883]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C883691]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C8848D4]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CD8B992+3610402]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CDE1860+3962352]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CDD9D4F+3930847]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CAC3646+693206]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9A1628]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C99D934]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C99DA62]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF69C98E113]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF439B7614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF442C26B1+33]
```

It opens the tab but then fails right away.
Tried updating chrome driver multiple times, it works with out the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\Profile 3` at the end as below:

```
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3")
```

Comment: Its not logging me in as that chrome user. Before it would at least launch a tab with the chrome user but then it would break right after